# Continue script, once search will be done

Tags: powershell

I have command in the script to do compliance search(Microsoft Exchange) and it takes ~20 minutes and I need to wait until it will be done to use powershell. I need to continue script automatically, once search will be done. Here is example:

```
    ShowSearchResults 
    Write-Host "You can find search results under the following path: C:\ExportResults" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "Do you want to delete found mails? (y/n)" -ForegroundColor Green
    New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName $FinalSearchName  -PurgeType softdelete -Purge
```

And when I start "ShowSearchResults" I need to wait once it will be done. I need to show "Write-Host..." once search will be done, until it, I need my session.

I tried with Start-Job, but I didn't find the solution with this way

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good to me except for 1 misrepresented statement.

PowerShell, like most scripting languages, will execute the commands/statements in your script from top to bottom by default.

So your `Write-Host` will be executed only after the previous command is completed.

As for the "misrepresented" statement, you might've wanted to use `Read-Host` to get a user choice to soft delete your last search. So after small corrections, your code looks like the below,

```
#1
$ComplianceSearchJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

    ShowSearchResults

    Write-Host "You can find search results under the following path: C:\ExportResults" -ForegroundColor Green

    # Invoke-Item "C:\ExportResults\SearchResults.csv"

}

#2
Receive-Job $ComplianceSearchJob -Keep

#3
$DeleteChoice = Read-Host "Do you want to delete found mails? (y/n): " -ForegroundColor Green
if($DeleteChoice -eq "Y"){ # case insensitive
    New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName $FinalSearchName  -PurgeType softdelete -Purge
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Added `Invoke-Item` to open the `C:\ExportResults\SearchResults.csv` file in a comment.

**EDIT 2:** Used `Start-Job` to allow running as a background process.

Comment: Yes, but I need to see search results before delete them, so I need to wait until search will be end. So I need to do other work, while searching, and then to show me search results and give me choice delete them or no.

Comment: @Marat - Yes, `Read-Host` effectively helps you with that. `Read-Host` will prompt for your input thereby pausing further script execution. So you can open the results file and see if you want to delete the results.

I have added `Invoke-Item` to open the results file in a comment. You can uncomment the line if needed.

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstanding, I mean I need to start "ShowSearchResults" function and it will take ~20 minutes to complete, and I need to wait it's ending, and unable to do other actions in this session. I need something like Start-Job which will be in the background, and once search will be completed, my script will be invoked in console.

Comment: Okay, what went wrong with the `Start-Job` command? Any errors, incorrect results?

Comment: Posted an updated code block using `Start-Job`. Please check to see if that helps.

Comment: In this case, I will receive "Do you want to delete found mails? (y/n):" message, immediately, after job started, but I want to receive this message, once "ShowSearchResults" function will be done.

Comment: Until that, I want to do other work on this PS session